# Task testing in Google App Engine force synchronous task execution in SDK or wait on all tasks execution?

Tags: google-app-engine

Do you know how to force GAE SDK to execute task synchronously for unit test purpose to check result of tasks?

Do you know how to wait on all task execution in queue in unit test to check results of tasks?

Default asynchronous execution of task not allows simple testing so is not suitable for example to check counters after update with use task queue.

Consider testing such simple code (checking results after finishing test).

```
  payload = pickle.dumps(args, protocol = pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
  task = taskqueue.Task(url = TASK_ADD_ORDER_REVIEW_COUNTER,
                        payload = payload)
  task.add(queue_name = COUNTERS_QUEQUE)
```

It is possible to skip task.add and just call directly code from TASK_ADD_ORDER_REVIEW_COUNTER but it is very ugly workaround it should be simpler I think.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you split up your test in two parts:

1. check if the task as added
2. check that the handler which deals with tasks works as expected

For 1., I would use ext.testbed like this

```
from google.appengine.ext import testbed

def setUp():
  self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
  self.testbed.activate()
  self.testbed.init_taskqueue_stub()

def test():
  [do whatever triggers tasks]
  stub = self.testbed.get_stub('taskqueue')
  tasks = stub.get_filtered_tasks() # see (taskqueue_stub.py for details[2])
  [verify tasks is what you expected]
```

For 2., I would follow the [handler testing article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/handlertesting) and send requests to your task handler. After all, tasks are invoked as normal POST requests (params encoded as request parameters).

[1](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/handlertesting) http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue_stub.py#2453

Comment: Some question: Is testbed taskqueue stub executes task in same SDK thread - mean is it not blocked till request finish like it is when you spawn task in SDK - since it required to wait for finish?
How is counted task started and not finished?

Comment: The task queue stub will not execute tasks, only hold them in queues for you to check. The execution is something done by the SDK which is not part of the stub.

Comment: That is bad since we require testing of full flow - task should be executed at once without queue usage - in same SDK thread/call. See my comments in issues why it so important and CODE EXAMPLE how complex is achieve such crucial thing in testing - http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8392#c5

Comment: Where is that "handler testing article" you mention?, following that link only takes me to a def _Dynamic_DeleteGroup(self, request, response): method of the taskqueuestub

Comment: I guess you referred to this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/handlertesting